Is it possible to use HighCharts to implement some features of ReactFlow?
Recently I want to use HighCharts to do some features similar as ReactFlow.
My features:

I can design the element myself.
I can drag the element and zoom in/out the whole panel.

Is it possible to use HighCharts to implement them without ReactFlow?
If so, would you mind giving me some tips or information about it?
Thank you.
I've read the HighCharts document but can't find any type of chart can meet my requirements.

Is it possible, Yes. Is it easy/ straight forward, no.

Thank you @Rajesh, would you mind giving me some tips or information on how I should implement it?

What exactly would you like to achieve, do you have a design or prototype? Or maybe you are unable to reproduce the current logic in an online editor because your question is too general

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
